# Converting a .wav file to .mp3

Tags: python, audio, file-type

I have a .wav file that I want to convert into an .mp3 file.  I made a python program to do this, and it compiles, runs, and creates an .mp3 file, but when I attempt to play the file, I get an error message.  I assume the file is unreadable due to the way I created it, but I can't figure out why.

Here's my program:

```
with open('pcm-test-1.wav', 'rb') as f:
    data = f.read()

a = [255,254,0,192]
b = []

for i in range (223,len(data),2):
    a.append(ord(data[i]))

a.append(ord('T'))
a.append(ord('A'))
a.append(ord('G'))
for i in range(0,124):
    a.append(0)

for i in a:
    b.append(chr(a[i]))

string = ''.join(b)

new = open('newFile.mp3','wb')
new.write(string)
```

I did this in python, but an implementation in any language would work.  Thanks!

Comment: Where do you read the audio data from the RIFF file? Where do you compress the audio data?

Comment: The with open() statement at the beginning gets the audio data.  "Compression" occurs in the first for loop; I only copy every other data point into list a  (because samples in .wav files are 2 bytes long).  The compression isn't really the important part.

Comment: No, it doesn't, it only reads the bytes from the RIFF file. The loop does no compression; the compression is what makes it a MP3 file.

Comment: By audio data, do you mean the actual samples that would be played back, or the metadata at the beginning of the file?

Comment: @user8577930: *The compression isn't really the important part*: MP3 is all about compression, it is the **most important part of the format**.

Answer (score 1):

If you are open to external libraries, [pydub](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub) can do this very easily with least amount of code.

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.playback import play

#read wav file to an audio-segment
song = AudioSegment.from_wav("your_wave_file.wav")

#export audio segment to mp3
song.export("your_wave_file.mp3", format="mp3")

#play audio-segment
play(song)
```

Answer (score -1):

Your best bet is to do this with LAME. Once you have it installed do the following:

```
LAMEOPTS="-b 192"
for DIRECTORY in /music/*/*; do
if [ -d "$DIRECTORY" ]; then
echo "$DIRECTORY";
for FILE in "$DIRECTORY"/*.wav ; do
OUTNAME=`basename "$FILE" .wav`.mp3;
echo "$FILE" "$DIRECTORY"/"$OUTNAME";
lame $LAMEOPTS "$FILE" "$DIRECTORY"/"$OUTNAME";
rm "$FILE";
done
fi
done
```

Comment: Sorry I should have specified: I wanted to do this natively.  If I had to download anything, I might as well download software that does exactly what I'm trying to do.

Comment: aah ok no worries

Comment: @user8577930: good luck then, but compressing to MP3 is not as simple as just removing a few bytes from the RIFF stream.